# About Stokes' theorem

Tags: differential-topology, vector-analysis, differential-forms

I noticed that in the proof of Stokes' theorem on manifolds, the condition that the form $\omega$ is compactly supported ensures that the sum is finite so that we can change the order of sum and integral.
And now I want to find a example when the form is not compactly supported and Stokes' theorem won't hold anymore. I think I have to construct a special Partition of unity by functions with compact support. 
Can someone give an example?

Answer (score 4):

The problem you underline is not about Stokes' theorem. It is about the integration of a form itself. If your form is not compactly supported, then you cannot define its integral over your manifold. Simply think of the manifold $\mathbb{R}$ and a $1$-form $f(x)dx$, where $f$ is a non-compactly supported function.

Comment: Specifically, think about the possibility that $f$ is *any* non-compactly supported function.  The point is that even if sometimes it works out through an extension of the basic definition of an integral, this isn't generally the case.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate any smooth function f in $[0,+\infty)$. If Stokes workes, the integral should always exists and be equal to $-F(0)$, where $F$ is a primitive of f, because 0 is the boundary of $[0,\infty)$. We know it is not always the case.. (e.g. take f=1).